# How can I make 1,300,000 images into one array file?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have about 1,300,000 images. To reduce I/O cost, I want to make one file out of all of the images. 
So, file need to be (1300000, 256, 256, 3).

I intended to solve it with `numpy`, unfortunately, I can't read and write all the images at once because I have just 16gb ram.

Could you suggest some way to solve it efficiently?

Comment: Does your computer have hundreds or GBs of ram? If not then you're going to have a bad time trying to load that to the memory.

Comment: Asking this is like asking "How can I jump 15 storeys high? It's okay if I have to use a different brand of sneakers to do it."

Comment: You could use [`np.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to create such array, it would map to a disk file of hundreds of GB but it should work (provided you are on a 64-bit system). You can write the images one at a time and, when you finish, all the information should be in that huge file. I'm not sure if that is the best approach for the problem you are trying to solve, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to concatenate the images one at a time. Here is a possible solution using PIL/Pillow

```
import sys
import glob
from PIL import Image

def concat_two_images(image1, image2):
    images = map(Image.open, [image1, image2])
    widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))

    total_width = sum(widths)
    max_height = max(heights)

    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, max_height))

    x_offset = 0
    for im in images:
        new_im.paste(im, (x_offset,0))
        x_offset += im.size[0]

    new_im.save('concat_image.jpg')
    return 'concat_image.jpg'


first_concat_image = concat_two_images('test_image1.jpg', 'test_image2.jpg')
for image in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
     # TODO - Add code to skip the first 2 images
     new_image = concat_two_images(first_concat_image, image)
```